# Aliases are not working after updating to the latest windows 10 update

Tags: cmder

I recently updated my windows 10 laptop, and now my preivously working aliases are now not working. What could be the issue ?

Answer (score 1):

The command prompt in windows 10 has an option in properties to use legacy command prompt. Enable it and try again.

Got this answer from the cmder github repository.